# Specification Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, specifications

My problem,
spring boot data specification query not working 
The query below does not work.
I need to get the real stocks grater than zero.
Can you help me ?

My Entitys

```
public class Product {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ProductDetail> productDetails = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ProductDetail{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productDetail")
    private List<ProductStock> productStocks;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product product;

}

public class ProductStock{
    private Long realStock;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ProductDetail productDetail;
}
```

My Specification

```
public static Specification<Product> realStock(Long realStock) {
        if (realStock == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            ListJoin<Product, ProductDetail> productDetailJoin = root.join(Product_.productDetails, JoinType.INNER);
            ListJoin<ProductDetail, ProductStock> productStockJoin = productDetailJoin.join(ProductDetail_.productStocks, JoinType.INNER);
            return cb.greaterThan(productStockJoin.get(ProductStock_.realStock), 0L);
        };
    }
```

My Pom.xml

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<artifactId>jjwt</artifactId> version = 0.6.0
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
<artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId> verssion: 2.4.2
<artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId> version : 2.4.2
```

Comment: Why don't you use Spring Repositories? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories

Comment: Unfortunately, we need more information, for example, provide pom.xml. If your entities mapping works, then there will be some problem with your current chosen approach for handling operations above DB. Arigion mentioned the right way of using Spring repositories.

Comment: Thank you for answer. pom.xml was very large so I added like this.